# alert not showing getElementbyId in javascript

Tags: javascript, getelementbyid, alerts

```
function showPrice(){ 

    var a = document.getElementById("product_container15");

    if (a == "$1,599.00"){
        alert(a);
    }
    else {
        alert("$1,499.00");
    }
}
```

This is returning $1,499.00 all the time.  I know I'm doing this wrong, or maybe there is a whole different way to write this.  I want the alert to show $1,599.00 if the id is "product_container15".  If it's not then the alert will show $1,499.00.  Could someone show me how this is done?  Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

`a` is an element - do you want the contents?

If this is HTML markup, try [`textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Node.textContent) or (for IE `innerText`):

```
alert(a.textContent);
```

Or the equivalent (for text nodes) [`nodeValue`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/NodeValue):

```
alert(a.nodeValue);
```

If `a` is a form element (`input`, `textarea` etc...), use the `value` property:

```
alert(a.value);
```

Comment: .innerText is not cross browser safe, is it?

Comment: @Shane: Not it's not. Should be `a.textContent || a.innerText` then.

Comment: @Oded: I don't think `textContent` works in IE though ;)  See: http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_html.html#t07

Comment: @Felix - thanks. @ShaneBlake - yeah, all this pain just abstracts away (give me `val()` any day).

Answer (score 5):

in your case a is html object, so it will never be "$1,599.00" maybe you should try like this

```
function showPrice(){ 

var a = document.getElementById("product_container15").value;

if (a == "$1,599.00"){
alert(a);
}
else {
alert("$1,499.00");
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

That's because `a` contains an `Element`. To get the `html` of that element, do `a.innerHtml` or `a.innerText`.

```
var a = document.getElementById("product_container15").innerText;

if (a == "$1,599.00"){
    alert(a);
}
else {
    alert("$1,499.00");
}
```

Comment: Thank you. the id is within a <p> tag. The text in the <p> tag contains the price.

Answer (score 0):

I think both Senad and Mohamed are correct but both of them are assuming 2 different things. Sena is assuming product_container15 is an input whereas Mohamed is assuming it is a container element like a "".

So, just my 2 cents worth, if product_container15 is an "input" element then:

```
var a = document.getElementById("product_container15").value;

if (a == "$1,599.00"){
alert(a);
}
else {
alert("$1,499.00");
}
}
```

If it is a div, span or any other element then:

```
var a = document.getElementById("product_container15").innerText;

if (a == "$1,599.00"){
    alert(a);
}
else {
    alert("$1,499.00");
}
```

Comment: I can't enter all my code because too much text. i have to wait five minutes to enter more.  here is the first div...........   <div class="grid_4" id="product_container">
  <a href="images/02_md.jpg"><img src="images/02_sm.jpg" width="100" height="100" class="small" /></a>
     <p class="text">1980 Jeep Laredo <br />(Color: Lunar Silver)<br />4-door</p>
    <p class="price" id="1599">$1,599.00</p>
    <p id="viewButton"><input type="button" value="View More" onclick=""/></p>
  </div>

Comment: I tried revising the function
}`function showPrice(){ 

var a = document.getElementById("1599").innerHTML;
var b = document.getElementById("1499").innerHTML;

if (a == "$1,599.00"){
alert(a);
}
else {
alert(b);
}
}`

Comment: @Oded, pedrodg, thank you! - here is more html `<div class="grid_4" id="product_container">
  <a href="images/03_md.jpg"><img src="images/03_sm.jpg" width="100" height="100" class="small"/></a>
     <p class="text"> 1980 Ford Pinto (Color: White) <br />2-door</p>
        <p class="price"  id="1499">$1,499.00</p>
    <p id="viewButton"><input type="button" value="View More" onclick=""/></p>
  </div>`

Comment: does any of the code I just provided help at all?  Thank you for helping me learn.

Comment: @Mick, try using http://jsfiddle.net to put up your example code. I've put up a version of this with some slight modifications of your code, where I check if the object is null and it seems to work....http://jsfiddle.net/pedrito/syWCd/